# PHP - Parsing XML one line record

Tags: php, xml, csv

I have the following issue. I have an XML file with the following structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Stocproduse>
<record ProdusId="1622" Stoc="11.00"/>
<record ProdusId="1632" Stoc="11.00"/>
</Stocproduse>
```

I'm trying to use the following PHP script to insert the data into a csv file, but it doesn't work:

```
$filexml='/var/www/html/site.com/Stoc_produse.xml';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($filexml);
$f = fopen('/var/www/html/site.com/stoc_produse.csv', 'w');
foreach($xml->record as $record){
$values = array("ProdusId" => $record->ProdusId, "Stoc" => $record->Stoc);
    fputcsv($f, $values,','," ");
}
fclose($f);
```

However, if I convert the XML structure in the following way it works:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Stocproduse>
<record>
<ProdusId>1622</ProdusId>
<Stoc>11.00</Stoc>
</record>
<record>
<ProdusId>1623</ProdusId>
<Stoc>11.00</Stoc>
</record>
</Stocproduse>
```

Does anyone have any idea what modifications I should make to the php script in order for it to work with the first xml structure?
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access XML node elements in one of two ways:

1. The aforementioned [PHP SimpleXmlElement Attributes function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php);
2. Direct access using `['']`.

Since there are a lot of examples of the 1st method I leave you with a working example of the 2nd one:

```
<?php
$xml = <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Stocproduse>
    <record ProdusId="1622" Stoc="11.00"/>
    <record ProdusId="1632" Stoc="11.00"/>
</Stocproduse>
XML;

$sxe = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);

foreach($sxe->record as $record){
    $values = array("ProdusId" => $record['ProdusId'], "Stoc" => $record['Stoc']);
}

print_r($values);
```

###Output:

```
Array
(
    [ProdusId] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [0] => 1632
    )

    [Stoc] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [0] => 11.00
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to get the data from the SimpleXmlElement attributes.

Check the following: [PHP SimpleXmlElement Attributes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php)

Answer (score 1):

try using

```
$xml->record[0]->attributes()
```

instead of

```
$xml->record
```

to learn about it click [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php)